# Tag parameters with commas in Azure Search tag boosting

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search

We're using tag boosting on a scoring profile in Azure Search to boost results based on the number of intersecting strings.

```
ie. 
Doc1 has { id: 1, name: "thing", stuff:["1 stuff","2 stuff","3,4,5 stuff"] } 
Doc2 has { id: 2, name: "thing2", stuff:["1 stuff","2 stuff"] }
```

Searching with the scoring parameter as `stuffParam:1 stuff,2 stuff` is fine.

But it falls apart when trying to boost for `stuffParam:1 stuff,3,4,5 stuff` as the commas separation in the querystring break it.

Is there a way to escape commas, or is punctuation ignored, or is this not possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was due to a bug in Azure Search that has now been fixed. Instead of the old syntax with the colon separator, you can now use a new syntax with a dash separator and use quotes to escape any tags that contain commas. For example, this:

```
stuffParam:1 stuff,3,4,5 stuff
```

Can now be written like this:

```
stuffParam-1 stuff,'3,4,5 stuff'
```

If you have tags that contain quotes, you can double them up to escape them. For example:

```
stuffParam-'Hello, O''Brien'
```

Will match the tag "Hello, O'Brien".

If you use version 1.1.2 or newer of the Azure Search .NET SDK, the `ScoringParameter` class now does all this for you.

Comment: @Fiddles The bug has now been fixed. The API documentation has not yet been updated, so I've described how to use the new syntax in my answer.